# Can I trust Origin the same way I trust Steam?

Tags: origin, drm

I would like to get the same type of answers [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2459/can-i-trust-steam-powered-games-is-there-any-unwanted-behavior-installed-with) got.

> - Can I trust this "Origin" DRM (Digital Rights Management) software    platform?
> - Has anybody done any independent verification on how this platform       works?
> - Does the "Origin" platform install anything particularly nasty or       unwanted on my computer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

I've heard a lot of bad things about their client, their EULA and complaints that Origin is "spyware":

- [EA's Origin Sends Personal Data to Third Parties](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/Origin-EULA-PC-Gaming-Glorified-Spyware-DRM,13285.html)
- [EA Says Origin Isn't Spyware, Although It Does Scan Your Entire PC](http://www.cinemablend.com/games/EA-Says-Origin-Isn-t-Spyware-Although-It-Does-Scan-Your-Entire-PC-36690.html)

And from [What’s The Deal With EA’s Origin & Is It Really That Bad?](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/whats-deal-eas-origin-bad/):

> #### Conclusion
>
> Origin isn’t terrible, but it doesn’t really offer gamers anything new. From an end-user standpoint this is just another piece of middleware, sitting between the internet and your purchases.

Steam has been tested, and is used by a company with a much better record and repuation as a company. Valve probably had the same issues (maybe worse, in some respects) while growing Steam, but those issues have long been ironed out and I don't remember any EULA-type issues.

I really wanted to play ME3, but personally I won't use "yet another client" (much less one with such attached controversy), so they've lost my dollars until they sell on Steam (without requiring third-party DRM).

Answer (score 9):

> Can I trust this "Origin" DRM (Digital Rights Management) software platform?

Yes. It is fundamentally not worse than Steam as a DRM platform, although it doesn't have as many bells and whistles.

> Has anybody done any independent verification on how this platform works?

Not that I'm aware of. "Independent" is practically impossible in a corporate environment, especially with a company as big as EA. Why would they let an outsider into their system, and how could any outsider they nominated be considered independent?

> Does the "Origin" platform install anything particularly nasty or unwanted on my computer?

No, Origin doesn't install anything that a reasonable person would consider malware/nasty.

Comment: "Origin doesn't install anything that a reasonable person would consider malware/nasty." Unless you buy _Street Fighter X Tekken_. Then it installs _Street Fighter X Tekken_.